# dpkg : error processing package (--install)

Tags: 18.04, dpkg

I am kinda new to terminal stuff and I need your help. I tried to install XArp on my machine with dpkg, but it needs packages, that I don't know how to install. I only tried to install libwxgtk2.8-0, but it can't be found. Here is what it says:

```
dave@dave-HP-ProDesk-600-G2-SFF:~$ sudo dpkg -i xarp-2.2.2-amd64-ubuntu-10.04.1.deb
(Reading database ... 345629 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack xarp-2.2.2-amd64-ubuntu-10.04.1.deb ...
Unpacking xarp (2.2.2) over (2.2.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xarp:
 xarp depends on libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8); however:
  Package libwxgtk2.8-0 is not installed.
 xarp depends on libxerces-c3.1 (>= 3.1); however:
  Package libxerces-c3.1 is not installed.
 xarp depends on menu; however:
  Package menu is not installed.
 xarp depends on arptables; however:
  Package arptables is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xarp (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xarp
```

Thank you for help:)

Comment: What OS version are you using?  It looks to me like you're trying to use an Ubuntu Lucid (10.04) package.  These packages are likely 'too old' in terms of dependencies and software versions to work properly...

Comment: @ThomasWard I am using 18.04. What should I do, if it is "out of date"?

Comment: @N0rbert I don't think so, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Then please shed some light on the source of xarp deb archive. Where did you downloaded it? Why does it named *...10.04.*?

Comment: @N0rbert it's from official web http://www.xarp.net/ 
Maybe it's just outdated program and I need to use something else.

Answer (score 8):

Please try to fix the dependency error by running this command.

```
~$sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 3):

The dependencies of Xarp package are not contained in 18.04 LTS repository, but we can get and install them from 14.04 LTS repository manually (**be careful, they will not receive any security updates**) with steps below:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.3_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.3_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/libwxbase2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libwxbase2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xerces-c/libxerces-c3.1_3.1.1-5.1+deb8u4build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libxerces-c3.1_3.1.1-5.1+deb8u4build0.14.04.1_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./xarp-2.2.2-amd64-ubuntu-10.04.1.deb
```

and enjoy:

> ```
> $ xarp --version
> XArp - Advanced ARP Spoofing Detection
> version XArp 2.2.2
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, for the help!
But when I run `$ xarp --version` I yet get this:
`Gtk-Message: 21:57:31.413: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"`
`Gtk-Message: 21:57:31.606: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`

Comment: Use `sudo apt install overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 libcanberra-gtk-module` to remove these messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have dependencies issue. It means that package you want to install manually requires another packages to be operational. 
Try to execute `apt install -f`atrer `dpkg`
This should fix dependencies issue.

Comment: I already did this, but it is still the same. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

First install "apt install -f " then try to install Team Viewer by using this command  sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_14.4.2669_amd64.deb

Comment: Are you sure that you answered the right question?